# Dependency issue with Sencha production build

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-touch, production

I encounter a problem with this code:

```
console.log('Before define Foo.Bar');

Ext.define('Foo.Bar', {
  requires: [
    'Foo.Some'
  ],
  singleton: true,
  constructor: function () {
    console.log('Foo.Bar constructed');
    console.log(Foo.Some);
  }
});

console.log('Before define Foo.Some');

Ext.define('Foo.Some', {});
```

In the production build, I get an error when I try to use Foo.Some in the Foo.Bar constructor => "Foo is undefined".

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are they defined in the same file? They shouldn't be... maybe that's causing the issue.

Comment: Is `Foo.Some` defined as singelton?
You reference it like a singelton, but in the config singleton is missing.